# Pass to the next number in a loop in range python

Tags: python

I am currently working to do a blackjack game, and I can't figure out how to switch to the next number in a in range loop when the player doesn't want a new card. here's the code :

```
import random


#cards
cartes = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,10,10,10,11 ]*4
#nombre de joueurs
nb = int(input("nombre de joueurs(max 5): "))
croupier = []
joueurs = []
x = True
random.shuffle(cartes)
for i in range(nb):
    joueurs.append([])
    joueurs[i].append(cartes[i])
    joueurs[i].append(cartes[i+nb+1])
    croupier.append(cartes[nb])
    print("main du joueur",i+1,":",joueurs[i])
print("main du croupier : [",croupier[0],", ?]")
t = True

while t:
    for a in range(nb):
        while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21:
            ask = input("Carte {} ?(oui ou non)".format(a+1))
            if ask == "oui":
                joueurs[a].append(cartes[a+nb+2])
                print(joueurs[a])
            else:
                print("Joueur",a+1,"a:",sum(joueurs[a]),"points")
                t = False
        if sum(joueurs[a]) == 21:
            print("joueur",a+1,"a BLACKJACK")
        elif sum(joueurs[a]) > 21:
            print("joueur",a+1,"a perdu")
            t = False
```

The part that doesn't work as I want :

```
while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21:
            ask = input("Carte {} ?(oui ou non)".format(a+1))
            if ask == "oui":
                joueurs[a].append(cartes[a+nb+2])
                print(joueurs[a])
            else:
                print("Joueur",a+1,"a:",sum(joueurs[a]),"points")
                t = False
```

How do I pass to the next number when ask == "non" ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: `continue`? `break`? It's hard to say. Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I couldn't have know which of the two statements you needed. So, your question is answered then?

Comment: yes thanks for your help ! sorry for the bad question, I' ll read the How to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `break` statement.

```
while sum(joueurs[a]) < 21:
            ask = input("Carte {} ?(oui ou non)".format(a+1))
            if ask == "oui":
                joueurs[a].append(cartes[a+nb+2])
                print(joueurs[a])
            else:
                print("Joueur",a+1,"a:",sum(joueurs[a]),"points")
                t = False
                # add this
                break
```